# SQL Replication - Does simply adding an article cause it to replicate?

Tags: sql, replication

I am adding SQL Replication (Transactional, single-publisher/distributor with many subscribers, using SQL 2005) to a website and have searched everywhere in the manual and on Google for this.

I am curious -- do I have to actually create a snapshot for new objects to get propagated, or is adding that new object (e.g., table, stored procedure, function) to the list propagate it to the remote subscribers?

---

Thank you, but I'm still confused.  I have a standard Transactional Replication with Initial Snapshot working, where the Master SQL 2005 database is indeed synchronized with a subscribing node (machine).  But when I add new sprocs or tables to the publisher, and add them as an Article to the Publication, they do not seem to automatically carry over to the subscribing box.  Checking properties of both the subscription and the publisher doesn't seem to reveal any setting that would replicate these changes.  (I do have "replicate schema changes turned ON.)  I have to be missing something simple... it can't really be true that every time I create a new sproc or table or UDF, that I have to generate a new snapshot of the entire DB, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the snapshot, but it will only propagate what has changed (what is new).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration of the subscriptions you may or may not have to explicitly update them after adding a new article.

[MSDN Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146887(SQL.90).aspx)